# Can I travel to Australia for leisure but on a business visitor visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia, business-travel, change-purpose-of-travel

I have a two years Australian business visitor visa with multiple entry option. This visa lets me attend business related workshops for a project undertaken by our parent company which is located in Sydney. Now I want to explore this country and was hoping to spend my next holiday in Australia. For this purpose, do I need to re-apply for a new tourist visa or my business visitor visa will suffice all requirements?

Comment: Eh? Exactly which visa do you have?

Answer (score 3):

You mention having a multiple-entry a business visitor visa. I can't find this type of visa on [the Australian Department of Immigration and Border Protection website](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi). I am therefore assuming that you have a visitor visa, rather than a working holiday or a temporary/permanent resident.

[All three Australian Visitor visas -- Visitor, Electronic Travel Authority and eVisitor -- allow for both tourism and business visitor activities.](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi/Visi)

> ### Visitor visa (subclass 600)
>
> This visa is for people travelling to Australia:
>
> - As a tourist
> - For business visitor activities
> - To see family
> - On tour with a registered travel agent from the People’s Republic of China
>
> The visa allows you to visit Australia for a period as determined by the Minister.
>
> See > [Visitor visa (subclass 600)](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-)
>
> ### Electronic Travel Authority visa (subclass 601)
>
> This visa is for people travelling to Australia:
>
> - As a tourist
> - For business visitor activities
>
> In most cases, this visa allows you to visit Australia on multiple occasions within 12 months from the date of the grant of the visa or the life of the visa holder’s passport (whichever is shorter) for three months at a time.
>   You must be outside Australia when the Electronic Travel Authority visa is granted or, if you apply for it while you are in immigration clearance, then you must be in immigration clearance at the time it is granted.
>
> See > [Electronic Travel Authority) visa (subclass 601)](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/601-)
>
> ### eVisitor (subclass 651)
>
> This is a free visa for certain people travelling to Australia:
>
> - As a tourist
> - For business visitor activities
>
> This visa allows you to visit Australia for three months at a time and travel to and enter Australia on multiple occasions within 12 months from the date the visa is granted.
>
> See > [eVisitor (subclass 651)](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-)

Therefore you shouldn't need to apply for a new visa if you wish to visit Australia for tourism with your existing visitor visa. Just make sure that you don't stay longer than the allowed period.

Comment: There's also [Temporary Work (Short Stay Activity) visa (subclass 400)](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/400-), which could be what the OP has.

Comment: @GregHewgill Good to know. If i read that correctly that visa lasts for up to a maximum of six months (under special circumstances) and is not a visitor visa. Maybe we should close this as unclear since there's a lot of doubt on which visa the op has.