# Can I travel to Australia as a tourist on a business visitor visa?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia, business-travel, change-purpose-of-travel

I currently hold a multiple-entry business visitor (subclass 600) visa for Australia valid until January 2020, and I have traveled to Sydney multiple times before for business.

I am planning to spend my next holiday (i.e., next month) in other parts of Australia (Queensland & Victoria). For this purpose, do I need to apply for a tourist visa or will my business visitor visa work?

**Note:** I have already looked at a similar query raised here but there was no definite answer to it.

[Can I travel to Australia for leisure but on a business visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64469/can-i-travel-to-australia-for-leisure-but-on-a-business-visitor-visa)

**Edit**: My plan to visit Australia last year was canceled but in May 2018, I went there as a tourist on my business visa and didn't face any issue with immigration.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to the question you linked to?

Comment: I have never been at a border as strict as Australia. I would read this entire trough before going there as it was of big help to me: http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visi

Comment: Glad that you were allowed. What did they ask at immigration? Did you declare that you have a Visitor Visa- Business but are travelling this time around for Tourism? Appreciate your response as i am facing a similar situation.

Comment: @PShah They didn't ask anything. I was allowed entry without any question. This is because subclass 600 can be used for both business and tourism.

FYI, I am again going to Australia as a tourist on my business visa in December this year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you can. Subclass 600 is a general **visitor visa**, and while there are different streams to qualify for one, once granted they are  valid both for business and leisure.

https://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/600-

Note that on arrival, you may be asked to justify that you're a genuine tourist, but hotel bookings, proof of funds and a history of travel should be sufficient.