# Can I travel to Australia on a business trip using my tourist stream visitor visa?

Tags: visas, australia, business-travel

I know it has been answered here that you can travel as a tourist on a business stream of subclass 600.

[Can I travel to Australia as a tourist on a business visitor visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92371/can-i-travel-to-australia-as-a-tourist-on-a-business-visitor-visa)

But another online source suggested otherwise that the purpose of your trip must be that of the stream you've been granted a visa for.

http://www.australiaforum.com/visas-immigration/58962-holidaying-visitor-fa-600-business-stream-visa.html

Also on my grant, it is stating clearly it is on a "Tourist" stream. So I'm a little worried if I should be applying for another one of a "correct" stream or not. Anyone on a similar situation recently or got any official quote from the Aussie immigration?

Comment: The official source is in the answer that you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibly not.** You should check the conditions imposed on your visa.  These should be listed in your grant notice or you can retrieve it from the [VEVO service](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/Busi/visas-and-migration/visa-entitlement-verification-online-(vevo)).

If your visa imposes condition 8101, then you cannot use it for business purposes.  [Condition 8101](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018C00245/Html/Volume_3#_Toc511822555) states:

> The holder must not engage in work in Australia.

Visas issued under the Business stream would probably have condition 8115 imposed instead of condition 8101.  Condition 8115 states (emphasis added):

> The holder must not work in Australia *other than by engaging in a business visitor activity*.

The "business visitor activity" exception is what allows a Visitor visa holder (in the Business stream) to do things related to a business trip.